# Manually add a version of an article to Google Scholar?

Tags: google-scholar

I have a Google Scholar account with 1 article. It has been found and displays correctly by Google Scholar.

I have added the same article to researchGate as a PDF so people can access it for free. However, Google Scholar does not offer this version of the article on researchGate; only the payable versions. I added the article on researchGate more than 6 months ago. so I doubt it's a wait-and-see issue.

I've wondered if I can manually add it and googled the problem but people just say to click the "add manually" button. However, this only permits adding articles by giving names, references, etc., but not a link to the actual article. In my case the article already exists and I just want to add a *version* of it. The only place where it might be able to accept links is the "other" tab  (even though it is a conference paper and therefore it should go under "conference" and not "other'), where there is a source field. I added the same article again and added the reasearchGate link into "source" on the "other" tab, but if I look for my article on Google Scholar it still doesn't display the researchGate link to my paper.

How can I do this properly?